# How can I place my prepared statement inputs into my database

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm working on a practice form for prepared statements. My prepared statements go through but my inputs on my html form do not. Only Anton and Tanya appear in my database, but not what I input.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "test");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) { echo mysqli_connect_error(); exit; }

// The (?,?,?) below are parameter markers used for variable binding
$sql = "INSERT INTO people (username, gender, country) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $u, $g, $c); // bind variables

$u = 'Anton';
$g = 'm';
$c = 'Sweden';
$stmt->execute(); // execute the prepared statement

$u = 'Tanya';
$g = 'f';
$c = 'Serbia';
$stmt->execute(); // execute the prepared statement again

$stmt->close(); // close the prepared statement
$mysqli->close(); // close the database connection
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Form site</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="people.php">
Username : <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
Gender : <input type="gender" name="gender"><br><br>
Country : <input type ="country" name = "Country"><br><br> 


<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to be collecting the values of `username`, `gender` and `Country` from the `$_POST` array rather than just HARD CODING 2 users in the code

Comment: Is this your full code? There is no code for reading and inserting the form data. You'd need to get formdata by using $u = $_POST['username'] etc. and don't forget to escape the input before inserting it (using mysqli_escape_string). I can write a detailed answer if you need further help with this.

Comment: ___Big Note___ there are no `<input` types of `gender` and `country` they should be `type="text"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use $_POST['parameter_name'] to collect variables.
Try this code

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) { echo mysqli_connect_error(); exit; }

// The (?,?,?) below are parameter markers used for variable binding

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$sql = "INSERT INTO people (username, gender, country) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $u, $g, $c); // bind variables

$u = $_POST['username'];
$g = $_POST['gender'];
$c = $_POST['country'];
$result=$stmt->execute(); // execute the prepared statement


echo "New records created successfully "; 

$stmt->close(); // close the prepared statement
$mysqli->close(); // close the database connection
}else{

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Form site</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="people.php">

Username : <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
Gender : <input type="text" name="gender"><br><br>
Country : <input type ="text" name = "country"><br><br> 


<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php } ?>
```